# Adding BBC Programme RDF feeds to Google Reader

Tags: google-reader, google-chrome

I would like to add feeds to my Google Reader notifying me of new programs from certain BBC series.

Chromium gives me a feed to add, but Google Reader does not accept it, giving me the errors

> "Oops...an error occurred. Please try again in a few seconds."

and

> "The feed being requested cannot be found."

Examples of the pages I would like to add:

- http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00qbq57
- http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b006mg74

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are RSS feeds for /programmes at the moment. See [BBC Programmes developers page](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/developers) for an incomplete list of what is currently available. Note that the XML serialisation is not RSS.

There are [iPlayer RSS feeds](http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/feeds), but these are far too noisy.

However, there are iCalendar feeds for individual programmes, detailed in a [BBC Internet Blog post](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/radiolabs/2008/07/some_ical_views_onto_programme.shtml). For example,

http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b006xxvg/episodes/upcoming.ics

gives upcoming episodes of Fawlty Towers. Also, just for debuts, replace upcoming.ics with debut.ics

If you add these calendars to Google Calendar, you can get an RSS feed for the calendar (Calendar settings > Calendar Address: > XML), as described on [Google's help page](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37106).